# How can you fetch json from an external url with javascript and/or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to get some json from this url : http://api.conceptnet.io/query?rel=/r/UsedFor&limit=3

I have a button that calls the function "jsonplz()" which is supposed to give me an alert with the fetched json.

My javascript looks something like this :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
</script>
<script>
function jsonplz(){
        $.getJSON("http://api.conceptnet.io/query?rel=/r/UsedFor&limit=3?callback=?",function(json){
        console.log(json);
        });
}
</script>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to fetch is as jsonp, hence why I added " ?callback=? " at the end of the url, otherwise if I was trying to get it as json, my browser would have blocked me.

Here's the problem : it still doesn't work. I get this error on the firefox console when I call jsonplz() :

**Warning** : *The script from “https://api.conceptnet.io/query?rel=/r/UsedFor&limit=3?callback=jQuery331030366838930478535_1646253265514&_=1646253265515” was loaded even though its MIME type (“application/json”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type*.

**Error** : *Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'*

Any solution to either solve this error or any other way to retrieve json from an external url without downloading additional third party software is appreciated

Comment: The answer from that URL isn't really a JSON. it sends 3 files (one HTML and 2 JS files)

Comment: @medilies — It is JSON (usually, the server does content-negotiation); that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Quentin check the network tab. The response say *This is an HTML rendering of the ConceptNet API response.*

Comment: @medilies — That's content-negotiation at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see, I'm trying to fetch is as jsonp, hence why I added " ?callback=? " at the end of the url

The server doesn't support JSONP (and shouldn't, it is a dirty hack with security issues and we have CORS now).

Either:

- Change the server to support JSONP (not recommended; see above)
- Remove `?callback=?` and change the server to grant your JS permission to read the data using CORS
- Don't fetch the data directly from the client (e.g. proxy it through your own server).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would imagine I need to download a web server software, in order to allow me to change server permissions?

Comment: `http://api.conceptnet.io` is an HTTP URL not a FILE URL so it already comes from a web server

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand you, I'm obviously new to webdev, but does that mean I need the conceptnet.io servers to allow me with Access-Control-Allow-Origin * to fetch their json? Essentially, I don't have permission?

Comment: Yes. The server you want your JS to get data from has to give your JS permission to access it (since it would be a security problem if your JS could make Alice's browser with Alice's credentials fetch Alice's confidential data and give it to you)